# What is the Solidity interface for the RSK Bridge smart contract?

Tags: solidity, rsk

The RSK Bridge exposes its interface through a smart contract deployed at [`0x1000006`](https://explorer.rsk.co/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000001000006). I was able to find [the ABI file for the Bridge](https://github.com/rsksmart/precompiled-abis/blob/master/abis/bridge.json) on github.

I'm after a Solidity interface file instead - is there one available, and if so where can I find it?

Answer (score 7):

Since you have an ABI, put it in the file named ‘bridge.json’. Copy the script below to the file in the same folder and launch it in the Terminal command line like this: ‘node filename.js’. Then find your solidity bridge interface in the file ‘Bridge.sol’ in the same folder. You need node.js to be installed in your system to run this script.

```
const fs = require('fs')
/** Name of the bridge ABI file */
const bridgeABI = require('./bridge.json')
/** Filename for the generated Solidity bridge interface file */
const BRIDGE_SOL = 'Bridge.sol'
​
const functions = bridgeABI.filter((element) => element.type === 'function')
const stream = fs.createWriteStream(BRIDGE_SOL)
stream.write(`// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
​
interface Bridge {
`)
functions.forEach((f) => {
  // function parameters
  const inputs = f.inputs
    .map((i) => {
      // add 'calldata' to the following types
      const type = ['bytes', 'bytes[]', 'bytes32[]', 'string'].includes(i.type)
        ? `${i.type} calldata`
        : i.type
      return `${type} _${i.name}`
    })
    .join(', ')
  // function return values
  const outputs = f.outputs
    .map((o) => {
      // add 'memory' to the following types
      const type = ['bytes', 'string'].includes(o.type)
        ? `${o.type} memory`
        : o.type
      return `${type}${o.name ? ` ${o.name}` : ''}`
    })
    .join(', ')
  // record a single function signature
  stream.write(
    `    ${f.type} ${f.name}(${inputs}) external${f.constant ? ' view' : ''}${
      outputs ? ` returns (${outputs})` : ''
    };\n`,
  )
})
stream.write('}\n')
stream.end()
console.log(`The bridge was generated. Find it in the file ${BRIDGE_SOL}`)
```

Here is the interface, generated by the script above:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

interface Bridge {
    function getBtcBlockchainBestChainHeight() external view returns (int);
    function getStateForBtcReleaseClient() external view returns (bytes memory);
    function getStateForDebugging() external view returns (bytes memory);
    function getBtcBlockchainInitialBlockHeight() external view returns (int);
    function getBtcBlockchainBlockHashAtDepth(int256 _depth) external view returns (bytes memory);
    function getBtcTxHashProcessedHeight(string calldata _hash) external view returns (int64);
    function isBtcTxHashAlreadyProcessed(string calldata _hash) external view returns (bool);
    function getFederationAddress() external view returns (string memory);
    function registerBtcTransaction(bytes calldata _tx, int256 _height, bytes calldata _pmt) external view;
    function addSignature(bytes calldata _pubkey, bytes[] calldata _signatures, bytes calldata _txhash) external view;
    function receiveHeaders(bytes[] calldata _blocks) external view;
    function receiveHeader(bytes calldata _block) external view returns (int256);
    function getFederationSize() external view returns (int256);
    function getFederationThreshold() external view returns (int256);
    function getFederatorPublicKey(int256 _index) external view returns (bytes memory);
    function getFederatorPublicKeyOfType(int256 _index, string calldata _type) external view returns (bytes memory);
    function getFederationCreationTime() external view returns (int256);
    function getFederationCreationBlockNumber() external view returns (int256);
    function getRetiringFederationAddress() external view returns (string memory);
    function getRetiringFederationSize() external view returns (int256);
    function getRetiringFederationThreshold() external view returns (int256);
    function getRetiringFederatorPublicKey(int256 _index) external view returns (bytes memory);
    function getRetiringFederatorPublicKeyOfType(int256 _index, string calldata _type) external view returns (bytes memory);
    function getRetiringFederationCreationTime() external view returns (int256);
    function getRetiringFederationCreationBlockNumber() external view returns (int256);
    function createFederation() external returns (int256);
    function addFederatorPublicKey(bytes calldata _key) external returns (int256);
    function addFederatorPublicKeyMultikey(bytes calldata _btcKey, bytes calldata _rskKey, bytes calldata _mstKey) external returns (int256);
    function commitFederation(bytes calldata _hash) external returns (int256);
    function rollbackFederation() external returns (int256);
    function getPendingFederationHash() external view returns (bytes memory);
    function getPendingFederationSize() external view returns (int256);
    function getPendingFederatorPublicKey(int256 _index) external view returns (bytes memory);
    function getPendingFederatorPublicKeyOfType(int256 _index, string calldata _type) external view returns (bytes memory);
    function getLockWhitelistSize() external view returns (int256);
    function getLockWhitelistAddress(int256 _index) external view returns (string memory);
    function getLockWhitelistEntryByAddress(string calldata _address) external view returns (int256);
    function addLockWhitelistAddress(string calldata _address, int256 _maxTransferValue) external returns (int256);
    function addOneOffLockWhitelistAddress(string calldata _address, int256 _maxTransferValue) external returns (int256);
    function addUnlimitedLockWhitelistAddress(string calldata _address) external returns (int256);
    function removeLockWhitelistAddress(string calldata _address) external returns (int256);
    function setLockWhitelistDisableBlockDelay(int256 _disableDelay) external returns (int256);
    function getFeePerKb() external view returns (int256);
    function voteFeePerKbChange(int256 _feePerKb) external returns (int256);
    function updateCollections() external;
    function getMinimumLockTxValue() external view returns (int256);
    function getBtcTransactionConfirmations(bytes32 _txHash, bytes32 _blockHash, uint256 _merkleBranchPath, bytes32[] calldata _merkleBranchHashes) external view returns (int256);
    function getLockingCap() external view returns (int256);
    function increaseLockingCap(int256 _newLockingCap) external view returns (bool);
    function registerBtcCoinbaseTransaction(bytes calldata _btcTxSerialized, bytes32 _blockHash, bytes calldata _pmtSerialized, bytes32 _witnessMerkleRoot, bytes32 _witnessReservedValue) external view;
    function hasBtcBlockCoinbaseTransactionInformation(bytes32 _blockHash) external view returns (bool);
    function registerFastBridgeBtcTransaction(bytes calldata _btcTxSerialized, uint256 _height, bytes calldata _pmtSerialized, bytes32 _derivationArgumentsHash, bytes calldata _userRefundBtcAddress, address _liquidityBridgeContractAddress, bytes calldata _liquidityProviderBtcAddress, bool _shouldTransferToContract) external view returns (int256);
    function getActiveFederationCreationBlockHeight() external view returns (uint256);
    function getBtcBlockchainBestBlockHeader() external view returns (bytes memory);
    function getBtcBlockchainBlockHeaderByHash(bytes32 _btcBlockHash) external view returns (bytes memory);
    function getBtcBlockchainBlockHeaderByHeight(uint256 _btcBlockHeight) external view returns (bytes memory);
    function getBtcBlockchainParentBlockHeaderByHash(bytes32 _btcBlockHash) external view returns (bytes memory);
}
```

Comment: this script looks like it could be useful in contexts other than the RSK bridge!