# BTC - RBTC conversion programatically using RSK

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, rsk

I want to ask if there is some documentation in order to make BTC to RBTC convertion through backend. I know there are some options in order to achieve this thing, like exchanges and some apps, but I want to learn how to do this process from scratch. There is an option to do this? If so, where can I find the documentation?

Comment: if you want to do this with a UI, check out the 2way peg dapp; if you want to do this programatically, interact with the PowPeg directly. Get the latest peg-in address from the Bridge by querying `getFederationAddress()` in the bridge contract - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/68891025/194982 ... and makes sure you do not send less bitcoins than the minimum amount allowed by querying `getMinimumLockTxValue()`. Ensure total amount of bitcoins locked does not surpass the cap, by querying `getLockingCap()`. I'll write up a full answer shortly!